# "Universal" approach for subfigures inside an enumerate/itemize environment?

Tags: graphics, captions, enumerate, itemize

I wanted to find a "universal" way to insert images inside an itemize environment. At first I simply used figures+subfigures and it worked good except when there is a page break. The images should be after the first item

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} % Tipo de documento
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Codificación del documento
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificación del documento
\usepackage{amsmath}        % Paquete de herramientas matemáticas
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Facilita la inclusión de imágenes 
\usepackage{float}          % Posición de figuras
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption} %% cambia los captiones de figras
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chap test}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[7-8]\\
        \begin{figure}[h!]
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sinc1}}\\
                \caption{blablabla }
            \end{subfigure}
            \hspace{.5cm}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sinc2}}
                \caption{bleblelbe}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{bliblibli}
            \label{fig}
        \end{figure}
        \item \lipsum[5]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I decided to use minipage and it worked on page breaks, but it doesn't work out of the box since you need to verify it is not too close to the above paragraph when there are no page breaks, having to add a vertical space, otherwise it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} % Tipo de documento
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Codificación del documento
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificación del documento
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Facilita la inclusión de imágenes 
\usepackage{enumerate}      % Conf. extra a las enumeraciones
\usepackage{caption} %% cambia los captiones de figras
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}   

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chap test}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[5-3]\\
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \captionsetup{type=figure,justification=centering}
            \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
                \centering
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sinc1}}
                \subcaption{blalblabla}
                \label{fig1}
            \end{minipage}
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
                \centering
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sinc2}}
                \subcaption{bleblelbebe}
                \label{fig2}
            \end{minipage}
            \captionof{figure}{bliblbibli}
            \label{fig3}
        \end{minipage}
        \item \lipsum[5]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know that for all intent and purposes, minipage solution works just fine, even if I decide to add vertical space regardless of if it's needed or not, but it still kinda triggers my OCD. So, I'm looking for suggestions/ideas from others. Nonetheless, I hope this helps others in the same boat as me.

Answer (score 1):

The entire purpose of `figure` is to take the content out of the document flow, making it a floating insert that may be positioned elsewhere, even if you include `h` so that the possible positions include the current location.

As such latex goes to some lengths to normalise the typesetting so that it does *not* look like part of the list, the current indent level is discarded for example, as you do not want a figure on page 4 to be indented just because the source code happened to be in the source of a list.

So if the images are part of the labeled items the natural thing is just to use `\includegraphics` directly or if you really want a caption use a minipage of `\linewidth` and `\captionof` as you show, although usually better to have a paragraph break  (blank line) not `\\`  before the minipage, or put them inside `\begin{center}` which will add some vertical offset.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about \\, it seems to be a bad practice to use it. I'm using from now own \newline. About your suggestion, it seem that blank lines don't work at all, I had to use \newline twice for the images to accommodate properly.

Comment: @pollitoalabrasa newline is the same as \\ both are wrong at the end of a paragraph

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates a `myfigure` environment to allow `subfigure`s and `\caption`s inside a `minipage`.  No attempt was made to force caption numbers to be in order.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} % Tipo de documento
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Codificación del documento
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificación del documento
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Facilita la inclusión de imágenes 
\usepackage{enumerate}      % Conf. extra a las enumeraciones
\usepackage{caption} %% cambia los captiones de figras
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myfigure}{\par\vskip\intextsep\minipage{\linewidth}%
  \def\@captype{figure}}%
{\endminipage\par\vskip\intextsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chap test}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[5-3]
        \begin{myfigure}
            \centering
            \captionsetup{type=figure,justification=centering}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
                \centering
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
                \subcaption{blalblabla}
                \label{fig1}
            \end{subfigure}
            \hfill
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
                \centering
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
                \subcaption{bleblelbebe}
                \label{fig2}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{bliblbibli}
            \label{fig3}
        \end{myfigure}
        \item \lipsum[5]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```